# Splitting fields and Galois Groups

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, splitting-field

**Question**

Let's suppose I have two polynomials $f \in F[x]$ and $g \in F[x]$ such that:

i) $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq F$;

ii) the roots of $f$ belong to a field $K$;

iii) and their roots satisfy:

$r_g = \displaystyle\sum_i \left[ q_i \cdot r_{fi} \right]$

where $r_g$ and $r_f$ represents, respectively, the roots of $g$ and $f$; and $q_i$ is a rational number. **Since their roots satisfy the equation above, $f$ and $g$ share the same splitting field $K$.** Are the Galois Groups of $f$ and $g$ the same?

I.e., is it enough to say they share the same Galois Group?

I think so, but I cannot come up with a rigorous (even a good) argumentation.

Comment: What do you mean by $f\in \mathbb{Q}\subseteq F$? Did you mean to write $f\in F[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq F$?

Comment: Also, the equation involving the roots is not at all clear. Do you mean that for every root $r$ of $g$, there exist roots $s$ and $s'$ of $f$ and rational numbers $q$ and $q'$ such that $r = qs + q's'$? This will imply that the splitting field of $g$ is contained in the splitting field of $f$, but I don't see why the reverse containment should be true.

Comment: In any case, the Galois group of a polynomial $p\in F[x]$ is *defined* to be $\text{Aut}(K/F)$, where $K$ is a splitting field of $p$ over $F$. So if two polynomials have the same splitting field, then they have the same Galois group *by definition*.

Comment: @AlexKruckman thanks for the improvements, I think its more clear now.  iii) means that the roots of $g$, $r_g$, are linear combinations of $f$s, $r_f$, and the coefficients, $q$, are rationals.

Comment: Thanks for stating the definition. I was not aware of this conclusion from the definition, because I was not (I'm still isn't) sure the exact meaning of "$\textrm{Aut}$".

Comment: Ok - what is your definition of "Galois group"?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know what "$\textrm{Aut}$" (I know that it stands for Automorphisms) means and how the splitting fields relate to them. What I know is that Galois Groups have a close relation to splitting fields, which I understand. For me, so far, splitting fields are the minimal extensions of the "coefficient field" in which a given polynomial $f$ can be factorized into linear ones. Thus, being the field where the roots of $f$ belong to.

Comment: Ok, well before asking questions about when two polynomials have the same Galois group, your first step should be to learn what a Galois group is!

Comment: XD sorry. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have explained: if $K$ is both the splitting field of $f$ and of $g$ then the Galois group of both polynomials is $G$, the set of automorphisms of $K$ which fix $F$ elementwise.

However (and it is a big However) if we are interested not just in the abstract properties of $G$ but in how it acts on the sets of roots of $f$ and $g$ then these actions can be very different.

As an example take $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ which is the splitting field of both $f(X):=(X^2-2)(X^2-3)$ and $g(X):=X^4-22X^2+49$. Acting on the roots of $f$ we have that $G=\{e, (12), (34), (12)(34)\}$; acting on the roots of $g$ we have that $G=\{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. The subgroups of $S_4$ are isomorphic, but  not conjugate.

In fact polynomials $f$ and $g$ with the same splitting field and Galois group need not even be of the same degree. Amongst others there are quartics and sextics which have the same splitting field.

Comment: I have to understand better all these "isms" to fully get these conclusions. But, thank you for your answer.